# How to mock the JSF class UIViewRoot

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsf, mockito, jsf-2.2

I'm testing my JSF application (v2.2.14), but I've some difficulties because I'm not able to mock the UIViewRoot class.
When I try to mock this class with Mockito I receive the error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
...
...
caused by java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find javax.faces.LogStrings bundle
```

I use the viewRoot in order to manage the java.util.Locale of the application and sometimes I need to read this information.

In which way can I mock this class in order to continue my test cases?

Thank you!

Comment: please show the code.

Comment: Why are you attempting to mock the JSF API? You aren't creating a JSF implementation, but just a web application using an existing JSF implementation, right? You shouldn't be interested in testing the JSF implementation being used (as decent ones are usually already well tested), but your own webapp implementation (indeed, this requires a completely different testing approach).

Comment: You're correct. I don't want to test JSF and I'm not interested in. I want to test some methods in some controllers that contains code like this FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(). Nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I've wrapped all the code that depends from JSF in a class that now I can easily mock.

```
@Component
public class FacesComponent implements Serializable {

    public Locale getLocaleFromFrontend() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }
}
```

and then my test class is similar to this

```
    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private LocalDateConverter localDateConverter;

    @Autowired
    @Spy
    private FacesComponent facesComponent;
...
...
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
Mockito.doReturn(null).when(facesComponent).getLocaleFromFrontend();
```

Comment: Still way to error-prone... Using aquillian or similar is imo safer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PowerMockito, you can use the @SuppressStaticInitializationFor annotation to remove the static initializer. https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior

For example, if the code is:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class TestedClass
{

  public Locale getLocale()
  {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
  }
}
```

The following test will pass (JavaEE7, PowerMockito 1.6.4):

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @SuppressStaticInitializationFor({"javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot", "javax.faces.component.UIComponent", "javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase"})
    @PrepareForTest({TestedClass.class, FacesContext.class, UIViewRoot.class, UIComponentBase.class, UIComponent.class, Locale.class})
    public class TestedClassTest {

        private final FacesContext facesContext = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
        private final UIViewRoot uiViewRoot = Mockito.mock(UIViewRoot.class);
        private final Locale locale = PowerMockito.mock(Locale.class);

    private final TestedClass instance = new TestedClass();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);

    Mockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(facesContext);

        Mockito.when(facesContext.getViewRoot()).thenReturn(uiViewRoot);
      Mockito.when(uiViewRoot.getLocale()).thenReturn(locale);
    }

    /**
     * Test of getLocale method, of class TestedClass.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetLocale() {

        assertEquals(locale, instance.getLocale());
    }
}
```

Make sure you suppress the super classes of UIViewRoot as well.